# Scala constructor for case classes question

Tags: java, scala, hashcode

I'm puzzled by something in Scala.  I seem to have objects that have the same address, but different contents.  I came across this issue while using Kiama.  But to keep things simple, I boiled all the code down to this:

```
object CaseTests {
  trait Attributable extends Product {
    var parent: Attributable = null;

    private def setChildConnections = {
        var i : Int = 0        
        for (i <- 0 until productArity) {
            productElement (i) match {
                case c : Attributable => c.parent = this
                case _ => 
            }
        }

    }
    setChildConnections
  }

  abstract class Tree extends Attributable { def id = super.toString }
    case class Pair (left : Tree, right : Tree) extends Tree { println(this+" = "+super.toString + " = ("+left.id+", "+right.id+")"); }
    case class Leaf (value : Int) extends Tree { println(this+" = "+super.toString); }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val l1 = Leaf(1);
      val l2 = Leaf(1);
      val tree = Pair (Leaf (1), Pair (Leaf (1), Leaf (2)))
      val Pair(left1: Tree, sub: Tree) = tree
      val Pair(left2: Tree, right: Tree) = sub 
      println("left1 = "+left1.id)
      println("left2 = "+left2.id)
      println("left1.parent = "+left1.parent)
      println("left2.parent = "+left2.parent)
  }
}
```

When I run my test case, I get this as output:

```
Leaf(1) = org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@fe67d8d2
Leaf(1) = org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@fe67d8d2
Leaf(1) = org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@fe67d8d2
Leaf(1) = org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@fe67d8d2
Leaf(2) = org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@de2f8005
Pair(Leaf(1),Leaf(2)) = org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Pair@d8e41584 = (org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@fe67d8d2, org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@de2f8005)
Pair(Leaf(1),Pair(Leaf(1),Leaf(2))) = org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Pair@6a311526 = (org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@fe67d8d2, org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Pair@d8e41584)
left1 = org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@fe67d8d2
left2 = org.modelica.v4.tests.full.CaseTests$Leaf@fe67d8d2
left1.parent = Pair(Leaf(1),Pair(Leaf(1),Leaf(2)))
left2.parent = Pair(Leaf(1),Leaf(2))
```

What I don't understand (and I suspect this is because I am missing some subtle point about equivalence in Scala/Java or perhaps I'm simply misinterpreting the output) is how left1 and left2 appear to have the same address (or am I misinterpreting that), but different parents?!

If somebody could set me straight, I would really appreciate it.  Thanks.

P.S. - I'm running Scala 2.9, in case it matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`left1` and `left2` are not the same objects. Try `println(left1 eq left2)`, it will print false. The default `toString` method calls `Integer.toHexString(hashCode)`, so you're bound to get the same `id` if the hash code of two object matches. And here it does, because case classes automatically get a decent `hashCode` and `equals` implementation.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I assumed the "@" indicated an address.  But if it uses the hashCode then that makes sense.  As a follow-up, is there any way to access the address?  I see that `eq` is a natural way to check, but it is possible to override it (and therefore make it impossible to check if two objects are the same), correct?  Is there a foolproof way?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get the address, but you can always call `System.identityHashCode(obj)` to obtain a hash code based on the “address” (quoted because this is not the actual address as you would think of an address in C/C++).

Comment: Excellent.  I have heard quite a bit about this corner of the Scala/Java world.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: System.identityHashCode() is an excellent trick, but note that it's also not always guaranteed to return a unique result -- I've seen it return identical numbers for two different live objects.